# Jetson Nano And Yocto/poky Zeus

Tags: yocto, bitbake, nvidia-jetson, linaro

I'm attempting to use the newest Yocto release to build an image to my Jetson Nano. For this I need CUDA 10 which is part of the NVIDIA binaries needed for the Jetson Nano image build.

CUDA 10 only supports GCC 7, so to get this working I'm using the meta-linaro layer to add an external toolchain. I put in

```
GCCVERSION = "linaro-7.2"
SDKGCCVERSION = "linaro-7.2"
```

In my `local.conf` and add the linaro layer to my `bblayers.conf`. When i then run `bitbake image-name` it then fails with the following error:

```
WARNING: /home/tm/yocto/dev-jetson-nano-zeus/layers/meta-linaro/meta-aarch64/recipes-core/openjdk/openjdk-8_0.1.bb: Exception during build_dependencies for AUTOREV
WARNING: /home/tm/yocto/dev-jetson-nano-zeus/layers/meta-linaro/meta-aarch64/recipes-core/openjdk/openjdk-8_0.1.bb: Error during finalise of /home/tm/yocto/dev-jetson-nano-zeus/layers/meta-linaro/meta-aarch64/recipes-core/openjdk/openjdk-8_0.1.bb
ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /home/tm/yocto/dev-jetson-nano-zeus/layers/meta-linaro/meta-aarch64/recipes-core/openjdk/openjdk-8_0.1.bb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tm/yocto/dev-jetson-nano-zeus/layers/poky-zeus/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py", line 1302, in FetchData.setup_revisions(d=<bb.data_smart.DataSmart object at 0x7f3436da90b8>):
             for name in self.names:
    >            self.revisions[name] = srcrev_internal_helper(self, d, name)

  File "/home/tm/yocto/dev-jetson-nano-zeus/layers/poky-zeus/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py", line 1167, in srcrev_internal_helper(ud=<bb.fetch2.FetchData object at 0x7f3436df5b00>, d=<bb.data_smart.DataSmart object at 0x7f3436da90b8>, name='jdk8'):
         if srcrev == "AUTOINC":
    >        srcrev = ud.method.latest_revision(ud, d, name)

  File "/home/tm/yocto/dev-jetson-nano-zeus/layers/poky-zeus/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py", line 1558, in Hg.latest_revision(ud=<bb.fetch2.FetchData object at 0x7f3436df5b00>, d=<bb.data_smart.DataSmart object at 0x7f3436da90b8>, name='jdk8'):
             revs = bb.persist_data.persist('BB_URI_HEADREVS', d)
    >        key = self.generate_revision_key(ud, d, name)
             try:
  File "/home/tm/yocto/dev-jetson-nano-zeus/layers/poky-zeus/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py", line 1570, in Hg.generate_revision_key(ud=<bb.fetch2.FetchData object at 0x7f3436df5b00>, d=<bb.data_smart.DataSmart object at 0x7f3436da90b8>, name='jdk8'):
         def generate_revision_key(self, ud, d, name):
    >        key = self._revision_key(ud, d, name)
             return "%s-%s" % (key, d.getVar("PN") or "")
  File "/home/tm/yocto/dev-jetson-nano-zeus/layers/poky-zeus/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/hg.py", line 223, in Hg._revision_key(ud=<bb.fetch2.FetchData object at 0x7f3436df5b00>, d=<bb.data_smart.DataSmart object at 0x7f3436da90b8>, name='jdk8'):
             """
    >        return "hg:" + ud.moddir

bb.data_smart.ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable SRCPV, expression was ${@bb.fetch2.get_srcrev(d)} which triggered exception AttributeError: 'FetchData' object has no attribute 'moddir'


Summary: There were 2 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

So it appears there is something wrong with the `AUTOREV` usage in the jdk bbfile? Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: maybe use `meta-java` for openjdk instead of `meta-aarch64` ?

Comment: there are other threads talking about this issue, see [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/yocto@yoctoproject.org/msg42549.html), [here](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2018-April/040673.html), [here](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2017-January/034175.html).

Comment: For whatever reason it works for me on `warrior` branch but not the new `zeus` branch (even though the `openjdk-8_0.1.bb` and `__init__.py` apperently aren't changed from `warrior`to `zeus`). 

The main reason that i wanted to get going on the Zeus branch was because of OpenCV 4.1, but i found out the entire `meta-openembedded/meta-oe` layer (from `zeus`branch) is compatible with `warrior` branch, so i just replaced the one i had with the new and it seems to work.

Comment: using the patch from [the first link](https://www.mail-archive.com/yocto@yoctoproject.org/msg42549.html) you sent did not fix this problem. Same error appears